# Sort by length of factor

Tags: r

I have a factor within a dataframe. I would like to order the levels of the  factor from those which have longest length (most entries) to shortest length (least entries for that factor level.

```
 df<- data.frame(x= c("B","B","B","A","A","C","C","C","C"), y= c( 
 "2", "2", "2","1","1","3","3","3","3"))
```

And I which the output to be:

```
df<- data.frame(x= c("C","C", "C","C","B","B","B","A","A",), y= c( 
 "3","3","3","3", "2", "2","2","1","1",))
```

I have tried:

```
A.data$loc<-sort(length(A.data$loc))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, n := .N, x][order(-n)][, n := NULL][]
#   x y
#1: C 3
#2: C 3
#3: C 3
#4: C 3
#5: B 2
#6: B 2
#7: B 2
#8: A 1
#9: A 1
```

---

Or with `table` from `base R`

```
df[with(df, order(factor(x, levels = names(sort(table(x), decreasing = TRUE))))),]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way using dplyr:

```
require(dplyr)
require(magrittr)

df %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  mutate(count = n()) %>%
  arrange(desc(count)) %>%
  select(-count)
```

The output is:

```
       x      y
  <fctr> <fctr>
1      C      3
2      C      3
3      C      3
4      C      3
5      B      2
6      B      2
7      B      2
8      A      1
9      A      1
```